# Ошибка линковки Qt+VS

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, qt5

Использую библиотеки Qt5.6 под VS2013. В частности класс QTcpSocket. При динамическом создании объекта socket = new QTcpSocket(); возникает ошибка:

error LNK2038: обнаружено несоответствие для "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL": значение "0" не соответствует значению "2" в xxx.obj  xxx\Qt5Bootstrap.lib(qiodevice.obj)

error LNK2038: обнаружено несоответствие для "RuntimeLibrary": значение "MD_DynamicRelease" не соответствует значению "MDd_DynamicDebug" в xxx.obj  xxx\Qt5Bootstrap.lib(qiodevice.obj)

Но при работе со статическими объектами этого же класса такой проблемы не возникает, т.е QTcpSocket socket; проходит нормально. Подскажите, в чем проблема, куда смотреть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, в списке линковки оказалась как дебажная, так и релизная версии библиотеки с QTcpSocket.